# i want to save to CSV but array is 4D

Tags: python

i have a sliding window and i want to save in CSV file the results of the mean values of pixels of every window, but numpy gives me an error that cant a 4D array saved and needs 1D-2D. any advice please?

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


image2 = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

image = cv2.resize(image2, (224, 224))
tmp = image  
stepSize = 50
(w_width, w_height) = (100, 100 ) 
for x in range(0, image.shape[1] - w_width, stepSize):
    for y in range(0, image.shape[0] - w_height, stepSize):
        window = image[x:x + w_width, y:y + w_height, :]

       
        cv2.rectangle(tmp, (x, y), (x + w_width, y + w_height), (255, 0, 0), 2)  
        plt.imshow(np.array(tmp).astype('uint8'))
       
        plt.show()
        mean_values=[]
        mean_val, std_dev = cv2.meanStdDev(image)
        mean_val = mean_val[:3]
        mean_values.append([mean_val])
        mean_values = np.asarray(mean_values)

        print(mean_values.reshape(3))
        
        print(mean_values.shape)
        np.reshape(mean_values,(1,3))
        np.savetxt("stats.csv", mean_values, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first save any numpy array using `np.save` to file like

```
np.save('yourFileName', your_array)
```

and then load it using `np.load`

```
load_in_array = np.load('yourFileName.npy')
```

this may work for you.

Comment: it really works! and one more last question..i want so save all the values coming from sliding windows not only the last one! what could i do?

Answer (score 0):

Before saving it to csv. 
Just reshape the "mean_values" variable.

Try Below snippet.

`mean_values = mean_values.reshape(1,3)
np.savetxt("stats.csv", mean_values, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')`